# what is an efficient way to transpose a matrix in a text file?

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

i have a text file that holds a 2-dimensional matrix. it looks like the following.

```
01 02 03 04 05
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

as you can see, each row is delimited by a new line and each column is delimited by a space. i need to transpose this matrix in an efficient way.

```
01 06 11 16
02 07 12 17
03 08 04 05
04 09 14 19
05 10 15 20
```

in reality, the matrix is 10,000 by 14,000. the individual elements are double/float. it would be costly, if not impossible, to attempt to transpose this file/matrix all in memory.

does anyone know of a util API to do something like this or an efficient approach?

what i have tried: my naive approach has been to create a temporary file for each column (of the transposed matrix). so, with 10,000 rows, i will have 10,000 temporary files. when i read each line, i tokenize each value, and append the value to the corresponding file. so with the example above, i will have something like the following.

```
file-0: 01 06 11 16
file-1: 02 07 12 17
file-3: 03 08 13 18
file-4: 04 09 14 19
file-5: 05 10 15 20
```

i then read each file back in and append them into one file. i wonder if there's a smarter way because i know the file i/o operations will be a pain point.

Comment: It's only a touch over a gigabyte ;-)

Comment: Has programming been reduced to looking for APIs these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with minimal memory consumption and extremely low performance:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MatrixTransposer {

  private static final String TMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/";
  private static final String EXTENSION = ".matrix.tmp.result";
  private final String original;
  private final String dst;

  public MatrixTransposer(String original, String dst) {
    this.original = original;
    this.dst = dst;
  }

  public void transpose() throws IOException {

    deleteTempFiles();

    int max = 0;

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
      fileReader = new FileReader(original);
      reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      String row;
      while((row = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        max = appendRow(max, row, 0);
      }
    } finally {
      if (null != reader) reader.close();
      if (null != fileReader) fileReader.close();
    }


    mergeResultingRows(max);
  }

  private void deleteTempFiles() {
    for (String tmp : new File(TMP_DIR).list()) {
      if (tmp.endsWith(EXTENSION)) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(TMP_DIR + "/" + tmp));
      }
    }
  }

  private void mergeResultingRows(int max) throws IOException {

    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(dst));

    FileWriter writer = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;

    try {
      writer = new FileWriter(new File(dst), true);
      out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
      for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        out.write(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(TMP_DIR + i + EXTENSION)) + "\r\n");
      }
    } finally {
      if (null != out) out.close();
      if (null != writer) writer.close();
    }
  }

  private int appendRow(int max, String row, int i) throws IOException {

    for (String element : row.split(" ")) {

      FileWriter writer = null;
      BufferedWriter out = null;
      try {
        writer = new FileWriter(TMP_DIR + i + EXTENSION, true);
        out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        out.write(columnPrefix(i) + element);
      } finally {
        if (null != out) out.close();
        if (null != writer) writer.close();
      }
      max = Math.max(i++, max);
    }
    return max;
  }

  private String columnPrefix(int i) {

    return (0 == i ? "" : " ");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    new MatrixTransposer("c:/temp/mt/original.txt", "c:/temp/mt/transposed.txt").transpose();
  }
}
```

Comment: i see a lot of opening/closing on the FileWriter/BufferedWriter. should we just leave these writers opened and close them all at once at the end? or will that be a memory issue?

Comment: yeah, you can try out leaving them open, but eventually you should get an out of memory exception

Comment: other approach would be to find the biggest number that could be in the matrix and reserve a byte array of fixed length for every element. then you don't need separators, since the records would be of a fixed length. first step would be to transform the original file into a byte file and use the java nio `FileChannel` and its capability for random access (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) to jump through the original file offseting the position to pick the next number in the destination file

Answer (score 0):

The total size is 1.12GB (if double), half of that if float.  This is small enough for today's machines that you can do it in memory.  You might want to do transposition in-place, though, and that is a rather nontrivial task.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) gives further links.

Comment: thanks. i was trying to avoid learning something new because the problem i am trying to solve is not matrix transposition (it's a stumbling block). but i guess it's worth giving some of these previous approaches some thought.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to assess the number of columns you can read while not consuming to much memory. Then you write the final file by reading several time the source file by chunk involving the number of columns. Let's say you have 10000 columns. First you read the columns 0 to 250 of the source file in a collection, then you write in the final file. Then you do that again for column 250 to 500 and so on.

```
public class TransposeMatrixUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransposeMatrixUtils.class);

    // Max number of bytes of the src file involved in each chunk
    public static int MAX_BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 50_000;// 50 MB

    public static File transposeMatrix(File srcFile, String separator) throws IOException {
        File output = File.createTempFile("output", ".txt");
        transposeMatrix(srcFile, output, separator);
        return output;
    }

    public static void transposeMatrix(File srcFile, File destFile, String separator) throws IOException {
        long bytesPerColumn = assessBytesPerColumn(srcFile, separator);// rough assessment of bytes par column
        int nbColsPerChunk = (int) (MAX_BYTES_PER_CHUNK / bytesPerColumn);// number of columns per chunk according to the limit of bytes to be used per chunk
        if (nbColsPerChunk == 0) nbColsPerChunk = 1;// in case a single column has more bytes than the limit ...
        logger.debug("file length : {} bytes. max bytes per chunk : {}. nb columns per chunk : {}.", srcFile.length(), MAX_BYTES_PER_CHUNK, nbColsPerChunk);
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(destFile); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
            boolean remainingColumns = true;
            int offset = 0;
            while (remainingColumns) {
                remainingColumns = writeColumnsInRows(srcFile, bw, separator, offset, nbColsPerChunk);
                offset += nbColsPerChunk;
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean writeColumnsInRows(File srcFile, BufferedWriter bw, String separator, int offset, int nbColumns) throws IOException {
        List<String>[] newRows;
        boolean remainingColumns = true;
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(srcFile); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String[] split0 = br.readLine().split(separator);
            if (split0.length <= offset + nbColumns) remainingColumns = false;
            int lastColumnIndex = Math.min(split0.length, offset + nbColumns);
            logger.debug("chunk for column {} to {} among {}", offset, lastColumnIndex, split0.length);
            newRows = new List[lastColumnIndex - offset];
            for (int i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
                newRows[i] = new ArrayList<>();
                newRows[i].add(split0[i + offset]);
            }
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split(separator);
                for (int i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
                    newRows[i].add(split[i + offset]);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
            bw.write(newRows[i].get(0));
            for (int j = 1; j < newRows[i].size(); j++) {
                bw.write(separator);
                bw.write(newRows[i].get(j));
            }
            bw.newLine();
        }
        return remainingColumns;
    }

    private static long assessBytesPerColumn(File file, String separator) throws IOException {
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            int nbColumns = br.readLine().split(separator).length;
            return file.length() / nbColumns;
        }
    }

}
```

It should be much more effecient than creating plenty of temporary files which will generate tons of I/O.

For your example of a 10000 x 14000 matrix, this code took 3 minutes to create the transposed file. If you set `MAX_BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 100_000` instead of `1024 * 50_000`, it takes 2 minutes but consume more RAM of course.